# Inverse of a function defined as an integral

Tags: inverse

I am trying to get the inverse of: $$g(x) = \int _a ^x h(t) dt$$ That is, I want to find a general expression for $g^{-1}(x)$ and was wondering whether there are theorems I can apply. Thanks

Comment: No, there isn't such an expression. Not even for $g(x)$.

Comment: Possible dupilcate of: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1467784/inverse-of-a-functions-integral/

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $$g(x) = \int_a^x h(t)dt$$?

Comment: yes Nex thanks so much, I edited the question

Comment: Under some additional conditions, you have $g^{-1}(y) = a + \int_0^y (g^{-1})'(z) dz$ ... I am not sure that it is useful...

Comment: it actually seems to be an exact duplicate

Comment: yes it's a duplicate, fully agree. Didn't see it before, sorry about that